# How to accept the answer from linked "This question may already have an answer" question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, accepted-answer

My question now has a notification:

```
This question may already have an answer here:

    How can I know the DHCP settings offered by a server? 1 answer
```

How do I mark that answer as the accepted answer for my question?

(related: [What should I do if a duplicate has answers, but the original doesn't?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197685/what-should-i-do-if-a-duplicate-has-answers-but-the-original-doesnt))

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot accept answers on someone elses question, even if it is a duplicate. You can however upvote useful answers

Comment: A couple years later, the ability for users to accept and self-close their question as a duplicate was implemented: [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes)

Answer (score 3):

You can't accept answers on questions that were made a duplicate of yours. What you can do, however, is upvote the answer. If the answer was particularly helpful, you could award it a bounty as a thank you:

[image]